# Can I use xdotool key "ctrl+x" to exit nano when it pops up while pulling from git whilst running a shell script?

Tags: git, shell, xdotool

I have an update.sh that of course pull from git. The problem is nano is popping up with the MERGE_MSG and I would like to just us xdotool or something to just exit out. Is there a flag I can add to git pull origin branchName --flag?
I have tried:
xdotool key "ctrl+x"
xdotool keydown "ctrl+x" xdotool keyup "ctrl+x"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your update script, supply the `--no-edit` option, `git pull --no-edit`. or supply `GIT_EDITOR=true` in its environment, like `GIT_EDITOR=true git pull` or export it if you want to shut off all editors started by git commands the script runs.

Comment: I tried this yesterday as `git pull origin staging --no-edit`  I added just to the `--no-edit` to the end of the preexisting git pull. I never tried it witht he branch assumption and now I see you can `git pull --no-edit origin staging` as well! Thanks @jthill